# Python Pandas Reading CSV file with Specific Line Terminators

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe from the below sample csv I've been given but I am getting Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 0. I haven't had very much practise with treating bad lines but would really like to learn the best way to handle something like this. I have attempted many different options in read_csv such as error_bad_line=False but that has not worked either.

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 0
```

I am guessing that the line terminators of ," are causing the issue and I am guessing that the best way is to loop through each line and process so I came up with the below generator with help from a different  and was hoping I am close. Would really like to learn how to use a generator and yield for this also.

Sample data:

```
"USNC3255","27","US","NC","LANDS END","72305006","KNJM","KNCA","KNKT","T72305006","","","NCC031","NCZ095","","545","28594","America/New_York","34.65266","-77.07661","7","RDU","893727","
"USNC3256","27","US","NC","LANDSDOWN","72314058","KEHO","KAKH","KIPJ","T72314058","","","NCC045","NCZ068","sc007","517","28150","America/New_York","35.29374","-81.46537","797","CLT","317845","
```

I have crafted the below which removes last two characters but not sure hot to produce a dataframe from the lines:

```
def big_table_generator(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line[:-3]

gen = big_table_generator('../data/test_sun_file.csv')
pd.DataFrame(gen)
```

Comment: Can you explain how the data points in the sample data are formatted, and what you expect the DataFrame to look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by how the data points are formatted.  Those lines are just the lines from the file with comma delimited values and quote characters. Trying to just produce a dataframe with columns populated by the values similar to any read csv process.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error.  Fixed it by using the option quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE in read_csv.

For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, header = None, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')
```

Some info about why in the second comment here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5500

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with but I really wanted to avoid using list and append and take advantage of a generator instead but not yet comfortable enough working with generators.

```
def parse_file(filename):

    newline = []

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in reader:
            newline.append([s.strip('"') for s in row[:-1]])
    df = pd.DataFrame(newline)
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: nan if len(x) == 0 else x).astype(object)
    return df

df = parse_file(filename)
```